# Unable to setup jQuery sidebar plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to embed [this jQuery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Stylish-Multi-level-Sidebar-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-sidebar-menu-js.html) however it doesn't work for me. I think that the problem is in this line:

```
$.sidebarMenu($('.sidebar-menu'))
```

What could be the problem?

I treid to put it in document.ready and it doesn't work me, I worte it like this:
`<script> jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery.sidebarMenu(jQuery('.sidebar-menu')) }); </script>`

Comment: Have you included jQuery in the page? You'll probably also need to put your JS code in a document.ready event handler

Comment: does .sidebar-menu exist?

Comment: I treid to put it in document.ready and it doesn't work me, I worte it like this : <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
 
 jQuery.sidebarMenu(jQuery('.sidebar-menu'))

});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

How to use it:

1. Add references to jQuery library and the jQuery Sidebar Menu plugin's files into the html page.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar-menu.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sidebar-menu.js"></script>
```

2. You might need to load the Font Awesome 4 for menu icons.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css">
```

3. Create a nested html list for the multi-level sidebar menu.

```html
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li class="header">Navigation</li>
      <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v1</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      ...
    </ul>
```

4. Initialize the plugin and we're done.

```html
$.sidebarMenu($('.sidebar-menu'))
```